# Binomial representation of stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, binomial-tree

It is common knowledge that a random walk can be represented in the form of a binomial process. Is it possible to represent any generic stochastic process (including non-linear) of the form $dX=adt+bdW(t)$ (where $W(t)$ is a Wiener process) as a binomial process? Are there any papers which have dealt with this topic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a martingale $dX=a(X,t)\,dt+b(X,t) dW(t)$ where $a$ and $b$ are not constant, your tree **will not recombine** in general [edit]. This is the main issue. See for instance: Florescu, I. and F. G. Viens (2008, March). Stochastic volatility: [Option pricing using a multinomial recombining tree. Applied Mathematical Finance 15 (2), 151-181](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~viens/publications/old/quatrtree7.pdf). It deals with the case of **stochastic volatility**, i.e.

$dS=aS\,dt+b(Y_t)S dW(t)$

$dY=\alpha(\nu − Y_t)dt + \psi(Y_t)dZ(t)$

Comment: Very good point to relate the issue to the question of recombination!

Comment: While the trees do not recombine in general, it is possible to transform certain stochastic processes in order to obtain recombining trees. (see [Simple Binomial Processes as Diffusion Approximations in Financial Models](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~morales/docs/diffusion_binomial.pdf) )

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is trivially true once you know that [every continuous local martingale is a time-changed brownian motion](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/lecture-23-time-changed-martingales-and-planar-brownian-motion/).  Therefore, if you change your time variable $t$ in $dX=a\,dt+b\,dW(t)$ to the right $t^\prime$ you can get a standard tree representation.

Now, the correct time change may be difficult or impossible to figure out, so this theorem is of limited use.

One then becomes tempted to try making a tree adapted to the original SDE.  As @lehalle notes, you are then likely to end up with a tree that does not recombine.  You may be able to overcome that flaw by interpolating nodes *back* onto a recombined tree and applying some reasonable boundary conditions, but at that point most people just go with PDE solvers instead.